# C# Update Label depending on which item in the Combobox is chosen

Tags: c#, combobox, label

I have tried to change a label in my Form depending on what I choose in the combobox.
It does not work could somebody help.

Here is my code:

```
    private void cmbItems_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int index = cmbItems.SelectedIndex;

        if (index == 1 && index == 2)
        {
            lblAmount.Text = "Weight in gram";
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (index == 1 && index == 2)
{
   lblAmount.Text = "Weight in gram";
}
```

Use || instead... index can't be 1 **AND** 2 at the same time..
It could also be that you don't selection 1 is kg, and 2 is grams.. if that's the case, yoy could use a switch:

```
 switch(index)
  {
     case 1:
        lblAmount.Text = "Weight in Kg"; break;
     case 2: 
       lblAmount.Text = "Weight in Grams";
       break;
     default: 
       lblAmount.Text = "Weight in Grams";

  }
```

Comment: Thanks, What is better to use SelectionChangeCommitted or SelectionIndexChanged

Comment: `SelectionChangeCommitted is raised only when the user changes the combo box selection. Do not use SelectedIndexChanged or SelectedValueChanged to capture user changes, because those events are also raised when the selection changes programmatically.`

Comment: I think what that means is SelectedIndexChange or SelectedValueChanged will be raised whenever you change its value.. if you want to change the value made by the user alone.. use SelectionChangeCommitted.